# Unique validation is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Unique validation is not working in Laravel

```
  $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), 
                [
                    'firstname'=> 'required',
                    'lastname'=>'required',
                    'email'=>"required|unique:users,email",
                    'password'=>'required',
                    'phone'=>"required|unique:users,phone"
                ]);
                if ($validator->fails()){
                    return Response::json(
                        array(
                            'code'      =>  400,
                            'message'   =>  $validator->messages()->toArray()
                        ), 400);
    }
```

not working for non unique values

Comment: works fine for me ... would need more information about what you are doing I guess

Comment: Please add more explanation. Answerer can't reproduce it with a little code & explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), 
                [
                    'firstname'=> 'required',
                    'lastname'=>'required',
                    'email'=>'required|unique:users',
                    'password'=>'required',
                    'phone'=>'required|unique:users'
                ]);

                if ($validator->fails()) {
                   return $validator->errors();
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease TRy this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'fairstname' => ['required'],
            'lastname' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required','email','unique:users'],
            'phone_number'=>['required','unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);
    }

public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('register')->withErrors($validator, 'register');
        }

    }
```